# Touchable Opacity not working fine in react native? v0.66.1

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using react native 0.66.1 with react-native-gesture-handler and reanimated 2. There is very strange behaviour of touchableOpacity. Have a look below;

[image]

How we can rid of it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I found out what the problem was, If you add **elevations and shadow** to View then it will have strange behavior of TouchableOpacity. This should not be happen, it seems a bug. However, it was the reason behind.